# Añadir campo con inputs nuevo

Tags: javascript

### [EDIT]

He conseguido plasmar un segundo formulario casi idéntico, lo único que falla es la estructura tal y como se implementa.

Tuve que añadir una segunda función, mandando las magnitudes a través de la llamada, y clonar su estructura poco a poco.

Problema:

- Cuando doy al botón de añadir input (power, energy o btn) en el
  segundo formulario, se genera en el input al final, y con el label encima, no como en el primer ejemplo de formulario, donde el label lo suprime por el isFirst (cosa que no puedo poner otra vez en la ssegunda función) y lo añade en el sitio correspondiente.
- La estructura es lineal, es decir, no está separado por divs cada formulario, y todos se llaman igual.

Inserto el código verificable:

```js
class cls0{

   constructor(id, idtxt, params, jsonValue){

      this.id=id;                                                 // agregar ID
                                                                  //SACAR TEMPLATES
      this.tem = document.querySelector("#temp-form");            //sacar temp-form
      this.tem_c = document.querySelector("#temp-card");          //sacar temp-card
      this.tem_r = document.querySelector("#temp-row-input");     //sacar temp-row-input

      this.f0 = document.createElement('div');                    //crear div para el temp-form
      this.f0.innerHTML = this.tem.innerHTML;                     //asignar contenido del tem-form al contenido del f0
      document.getElementById(id).appendChild(this.f0);           //hacer hijo a f0 del id
      this.contentForm = this.f0.querySelector(".content-form");  //seleccionamos div.content-form de f0

      var ff = this.f0.querySelectorAll("button");

         if(ff[0]){ff[0].addEventListener("click", ()=>{this.sndFrm();})};//UPDATE TEXTAREA no se ve
         if(ff[1]){ff[1].addEventListener("click", ()=>{this.addFrm();this.sndFrm();})};//btn + principal
         if(ff[2]){ff[2].addEventListener("click", ()=>{this.delFrm();this.sndFrm();})};//btn - principal

      this.txtare = this.f0.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(".test-atex");
      this.txtare.value = JSON.stringify(jsonValue);
      this.sndFrm();
      this.sndTo();
      this.txtare.addEventListener("keyup", ()=>{
         if (!this.txtare.value){}
         else {
            this.sndTo();
         }
      });

      for (let i in params){
         var hi0 = document.createElement('input');
         hi0.type = 'hidden'; //cambiar a text si hay que verlo
         hi0.name = i;
         hi0.value = params[i];

         this.f0.querySelector('form').appendChild(hi0);
      }

      this.sndFrm();
   }

   addFrm() {//Es para añadir un formulario con el name-data 1 vacío
      
      const eventKeyUp  = item=>{item.addEventListener("keyup", ()=>{this.sndFrm()});}

      this.tc   = document.createElement('div');
      this.tc.setAttribute('name-data', '0');
      this.tc.innerHTML   =  this.tem_c.innerHTML;
      this.contentForm.appendChild(this.tc);
      this.tc.querySelectorAll(".lbl-tmp-crd").forEach(eventKeyUp);
      this.tc.querySelectorAll(".name_tarif").forEach(eventKeyUp);

   }

   addRowInput(mag, label) {// Para añadir los input
      let grup = this.contentForm.querySelector("div[data-group="+mag+"]"),isFirst=false;
      if(!grup){
         grup = document.createElement('div');
         grup.setAttribute("data-group",mag);
         this.contentForm.appendChild(grup);
         isFirst=true

      }
      let row = document.createElement('div');
      row.innerHTML =  this.tem_r.innerHTML;
      if(!isFirst){
         row.querySelectorAll(".box-label").forEach(item=>{
            item.remove();
         });

      }

      grup.appendChild(row);

      const eventKeyUp  = item=>{item.addEventListener("keyup", ()=>{this.sndFrm();});}
      const eventClick  =  item=>{item.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{this.eraseBtn(e);});}
      const addEventInout = item =>{item.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{this.addRowInput(mag, label);});}
      const eventDisable   =  item=>{item.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{if(e.target.parentNode.getAttribute("data-disable")==null){e.target.parentNode.setAttribute("data-disable", 1);}else{e.target.parentNode.removeAttribute("data-disable");}this.disAble(e)})}
      const eventAddIn  = item=>{item.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{this.addInp(mag, label);});}

      row.querySelectorAll(".lbl-tmp-crd").forEach(item=>{item.innerHTML=label;});
      row.querySelectorAll(".add-inp-value").forEach(item=>{let prefix=item.getAttribute("data-prefix");if(!prefix){prefix='plus_';}item.setAttribute('name', prefix+mag);});
      row.querySelectorAll(".add-inp-value"&&'input[data-name='+mag+']').forEach(eventKeyUp);
      row.querySelectorAll(".btn-event").forEach(addEventInout);
      row.querySelectorAll(".btn-event-erase").forEach(eventClick);
      row.querySelectorAll(".btn-event-disAble").forEach(eventDisable);
      this.f0.querySelectorAll(".btn-event-addFrm").forEach(eventAddIn);
   }

   addInp(mag, label){
      let grup = document.createElement('div');
         grup.setAttribute("data-group",mag);
         this.contentForm.appendChild(grup);

      let row = document.createElement('div');
      row.innerHTML =  this.tem_r.innerHTML;

      grup.appendChild(row);

      const eventKeyUp  = item=>{item.addEventListener("keyup", ()=>{this.sndFrm();});}
      const eventClick  =  item=>{item.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{this.eraseBtn(e);});}
      const addEventInout = item =>{item.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{this.addInp(mag, label);});}
      const eventDisable   =  item=>{item.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{if(e.target.parentNode.getAttribute("data-disable")==null){e.target.parentNode.setAttribute("data-disable", 1);}else{e.target.parentNode.removeAttribute("data-disable");}this.disAble(e)})}
      const eventAddIn  = item=>{item.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{this.addInp(mag, label);});}

      row.querySelectorAll(".lbl-tmp-crd").forEach(item=>{item.innerHTML=label;});
      row.querySelectorAll(".add-inp-value").forEach(item=>{let prefix=item.getAttribute("data-prefix");if(!prefix){prefix='plus_';}item.setAttribute('name', prefix+mag);});
      row.querySelectorAll(".add-inp-value"&&'input[data-name='+mag+']').forEach(eventKeyUp);
      row.querySelectorAll(".btn-event").forEach(addEventInout);
      row.querySelectorAll(".btn-event-erase").forEach(eventClick);
      row.querySelectorAll(".btn-event-disAble").forEach(eventDisable);

      var nm = this.contentForm.lastElementChild;
      this.contentForm.insertBefore(grup, nm.nextSibling);
   }

//Funciones temporalmente deshabilitadas
   sndFrm(){}
   sndTo(){}
   delFrm(){}
   eraseBtn(e){}
   disAble(e){}

}

window.addEventListener("load",()=>{
   var id0 = new cls0("t0", "ta0", {key:100});

   id0.addFrm();
   id0.addRowInput("power", "Power");  
   id0.addRowInput("energy", "Energy");  
   id0.addRowInput("btn", "Button");



// var id1 = new cls0("t1", "ta1", {key:101});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>LOGOS Energía</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- 1º -->
<div class="dv-content">
    <div id="t0"></div>
    <textarea id="ta0" class="test-atex"> </textarea>
    <button class='btn-event-sndTo' type="button" title="Actualizar">UPDATE FORM</button>
</div>
<!--
<div class="dv-content">
    <div id="t1"></div>
    <textarea id="ta1" class="test-atex"> </textarea>
    <button class='btn-event-sndTo' type="button" title="Actualizar">UPDATE FORM</button>
</div>
-->

<!-- 2º -->
<template id="temp-form">
    <form method="post">

        <div class="content-form">

        </div>
            
        <div>
            <button class="btn-event-sndFrm" type="button" title="Actualizar">UPDATE TEXTAREA</button>
            <button class="btn-event-addFrm" type="button" title="Añadir tarifa">+</button>
            <button class="btn-event-delFrm" type="button" title="Borrar tarifa">-</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>

<!-- 3º -->

<template id="temp-card">
    <div class="temp-card" data-group="0">
        <label class="lbl-tmp-crd" contenteditable='true' data-name="label_gruop">Tarifa</label>
        <input type="text" class="name_tarif" name="tarif"/>
    </div>
</template> 

<!-- 4º -->

<template  id="temp-row-input">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-label">
        <label class="lbl-tmp-crd" contenteditable='true' data-name=""></label>
        <button type="button" class="btn-event" title="Añadir">+</button>
        </div>
        <div class="sortable_p" draggable="true">

            
                 <input class="add-inp-value" type="text" data-group="" data-prefix='t_' name=""/>
                 <input class="add-inp-value" type="text" data-group="" data-prefix='v_' name=""/>
                 <input class="add-inp-value" type="text" data-group="" data-prefix='c_' name=""/>
              

                <button type="button" class="btn-event-disAble" title="Deshabilitar">X</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn-event-erase" title="Borrar">-</button>
                <div class="draggl">
                    <div class="bar1"></div>
                    <div class="bar2"></div>
                    <div class="bar3"></div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template> 



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sé que te esfuerzas en exponer el problema, pero me está costando enteder lo que quieres hacer. ¿Puedes "dar un paso atrás" y contar qué quieres conseguir sin entrar en el detalle de cómo? ¿Quieres crear un div como el de la primera imagen, para tener dos formularios?

Comment: Si, lo conseguí, pero de aquella manera, ahora edito. Y jope, de verdad que me cuesta mucho explicarme, no se cómo simplificar nunnca.

Comment: Simplificar es lo que haces con la experiencia, paciencia ;-)